# What are the pros and cons of using these Multithreading Models in a Client/Server Architecture

Tags: multithreading, server, client-server, client

In my classes of parallel programming the teacher mentioned three models, dynamic thread creation (create threads according to demand), thread pool (create a fixed amount of threads) and mixed or hybrid (create a number of threads at first, but you can create more if the demand increases too much and then return to the previous amount of threads when demand returns to normal)

I would like if someone could elaborate on the advantages and disadvantages of each model in general terms of performance, when it is best to use one in specific, etc...

Comment: Have you asked your teacher? You're paying an awful lot for that CS degree, be sure to get your money's worth.

Comment: Not that he haven't explained well nor I don't know anything, but it was long ago and I need to get a really good qualification on the next test, so I'm trying to understand everything perfectly and I thought that maybe I could learn something more than what I already know from an answer here.

Comment: I would like to know what's wrong with my questions... Why is it getting downvotes?

Comment: I think it is because the question is asking about clarifying something in an academic context and there tend to be a lot of questions that are students trying to get their homework done.

Comment: Should I delete it? or what can I do to improve the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick non-academic view:

**Dynamic model:**

- Pros: uses only the number of threads needed.
- Cons: the overhead of the thread creation and deletion during the processing.  Consider also thread switching overhead, if the number of dynamic threads increases over the hardware supported limit.
- Typical use case:  handling event driven processes/sessions (e.g. I/O), where threads are frequently waiting and performance of thread creation is small compared to I/O (e.g. new incoming network connection).

**Thread pool:**

- Pros: reduces overhead of thread management to the minimum. Constant throughput ?
- Cons:  If the size of the pool is too large (compared to hardware capacity or to processing needs), there might be an unnecessary switching overhead for unused threads.
- Typical use case:  handling work processes for queued input. More [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686760(v=vs.85).aspx)

**Mixed model:**

- can have the advantages (or the inconveniences if not careful !!) of both models. One possible approach is to size the a pool with an optimal size determined dynamically at runtime to maximize performance in view of hardware and processing needs.
- Pros & cons of hybrid models can't be analyzed in general: they must be assessed case by case.

Comment: Why `thread switching overhead, if the number of dynamic threads increases over the hardware supported limit.`? It should happen any time the scheduler give another thread the CPU, not only when the number of threads increases over the hardware, or I'm wrong?

Comment: @PatricioSard because if there are less active threads than available core there is no context switch required. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682105(VS.85).aspx But you're right: This is only true considering the total number of threads on the os accross all concurrent processes.